# Get property type of class that implements interface with generic parameter for property

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have interface with generic parameter to specify `Id` type.

```
public interface ITracbable<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }
    DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Then I create class and implement that interface.

```
public class Container: ITracbable<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have generic method that gets entities with specific type. And I had to add another generic parameter `TKey`, because I need to pass this type to another function `SafeConvertId<TKey>` so that I could convert `TrackedEntityId` (which is `string`) to an actual `Id` type of class that implements `ITracbable<TKey>`.

```
public List<T> GetModifiedEntities<T, TKey>(DateTime timestamp) where T : class, ITracbable<TKey>, new()
{
    var changes = this.GetChangeLog<T>(timestamp);

    var ids = changes.Select(x => this.SafeConvertId<TKey>(x.TrackedEntityId));
    ....
}
        

private TKey SafeConvertId<TKey> (string value)
{
    return typeof(TKey) == typeof(Guid)
        ? (TKey)(object)Guid.Parse(value)
        : (TKey)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(TKey));
}
```

How can I avoid `GetModifiedEntities` having seconf `TKey` generic parameter?
How can I get `Id` type from class and pass it to `SafeConvertId<TKey>`? Something like `this.SafeConvertId<typeof(T.Id)>(x.TrackedEntityId)`.

Comment: Where does `IChangeLogTracbable` come from? As an aside, what is a `Tracbable` supposed to be? The rest of your code looks to be in English -- did you mean `Trackable`, perhaps?

Comment: My bad, it's should be `ITracbable`. Edited that in question now.